# Exponent of a 'exponent subgroup'

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ a abelian group. I remember that the *exponent* of $G$ is defined as $\exp(G):=\min\{n\gt 0\mid x^n=1~\forall x\in G\}$

For all $t\in\mathbb{Z}$, I define $G^t:=\{x^t\mid x\in G\}$ (is a subgroup of $G$ because $G$ is abelian).

I now work with an abelian group with finite exponent $\exp(G)=n$

I want to prove that: $\exp(G^t)=\dfrac nd$ with $d=\gcd(t,n)$

> Let  $x\in G^t$, then $x=g^t$ with $g\in G$.
>
> So $x^{n/d}=g^{nt/d}=(g^n)^{t/d}=1$ and $\exp(G^t)\le \dfrac{n}{d}$.

**Q:** How can  prove that $\exp(G^t)\ge \dfrac nd$  ? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Suppose $\exp(G^t)<\frac nd$. Then prove that for each $g\in G$ we have $g^{d\exp(G^t)}=1$, which contradicts the minimality of $n$. [To show this, it is enough to show $g^d\in G^t$.]